# Как заменить видимое значение select option?

Tags: php

В моей форме есть выбор нужного параметра

```
<select class="form-control" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'selected_url' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'selected_url' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['selected_url']; ?>">
    <option style="display: none" value="<?php echo $instance['selected_url']; ?>"><?php echo $instance['selected_url']; ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $pay_url; ?>">Да, у меня PRO версия</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $free_url; ?>">Нет, еще думаю</option>
</select>
```

После выбора и сохранения данных, в поле выбора отображается заданный url (первый option).

Как заменить отображение url, чтобы пользователь видел не url, а его текстовое значение (Да, у меня PRO версия | Нет, еще думаю)?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```
<select class="form-control" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'selected_url' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'selected_url' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['selected_url']; ?>">
    <?php
        $pro_selected = '';
        $free_selected = '';
        if( $instance['selected_url'] == $pay_url ) {
            $pro_selected = 'selected';
        } elseif( $instance['selected_url'] == $free_url ) {
            $free_selected = 'selected';
        }
    ?>
    <option style="display: none" value="<?php echo $instance['selected_url']; ?>"><?php echo $instance['selected_url']; ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo $pay_url; ?>" <?php echo $pro_selected; ?>>Да, у меня PRO версия</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $free_url; ?>" <?php echo $free_selected; ?>>Нет, еще думаю</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Капитан Флинт, спасибо! Чего-то там не хватает, не работает. У вас еще вроде лишняя } в коде есть. `<option style="display: none" value="http://site.ru">и здесь site.ru - не меняется на название</option>`

Comment: @MicroRu поправил. И да, уберите `value` из `select` ;)

Comment: `checked` в коде проставляется но ничего не меняется, изменения видны если полностью удалить строку `<option style="display: none" value="<?php echo $instance['selected_url']; ?>"><?php echo $instance['selected_url']; ?></option>` но после ее удаления, данные более не изменить :(

Comment: @MicroRu блин. не checked. selected там. щас поправлю

Comment: @MicroRu поправил. пробуй

Comment: Капитан Флинт, здорово, работает! Большое спасибо!